# encoding in R doesn't work on server , but on local host it works

Tags: r

here data

```
mydat=read.delim("C:/Users/admin/downloads/tax.data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".",encoding="UTF-8")
```

text data cyrillic (on my PC, it is good reaD)

```
("Общая скидка по ФрешКарте", "Округление на вид оплаты", "Оптовая М03", 
"Оптовая М09", "Оптовая М11", "Оптовая М14", "Оптовая М15", "Оптовая М16", 
"Оптовая М17", "Оптовая М19", "Оптовая М20", "Оптовая М21", "Оптовая М23", 
"Оптовая М24", "Оптовая М26", "Оптовая ММ02", "Оптовая ММ12", 
"Оптовая ММ15", "Оптовые часы", "Персональная", "по акции", "по карте Город Товаров",)
```

But if i run this data on dedicated server, i see incomprehensible characters

[image]

why on my pc there is good with encoding , but on Dedicated server there are incomprehensible characters
How to fix it?

Comment: the reason you are seing incomprehensible characters is because your dedicated server does not allow the characters you have tried to display, and that is why you are seeing that. If it is not that your server might have restrictions on what kind of data can be sent or retrieved, I would try to retrieve the data back to your pc and see if it still has the encoding that you want. If it does that just means that the dedicated server is showing <U+034C> and such just to fill in for the place of a character. Other than that I'm not sure where else the problem could come from.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what's matter. Server was set on english lang. So i open  language and local setting in control panel,  I made the Ukrainian language the main language of the system and R read data without problems.